# Cannot load Panel in SwingNode with JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I’ve got a strange problem I’ve been facing for hours but I can’t resolve. I am working on an interface for a drone, and I need to load a swingPanel in my javaFX scene.  To do this, I use a SwingNode. But whatever I try, I can’t seem to fill the SwingNode. I don’t get any errors and the rest of the scene loads correctly. What did I do wrong?

DroneScreenController, the class which tries to fill the SwingNode

```
public class DroneScreenController {

    // Model
    private DataBean dataBean;

    // View
    private DroneScreenView view;

    public SwingNode cameraNode;


    public DroneScreenController() {
        this.dataBean = Model.getInstance().getDataBean();
        this.view = new DroneScreenView(); //Not very interesting, it just loads the fxml file
    }

    public void show(){
        createSwingContent(cameraNode);
        try {
            view.show(dataBean.getPrimaryStage());
            dataBean.getPrimaryStage().setFullScreen(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void createSwingContent(SwingNode swingNode) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            //Just random swing Panel for testing purposes
                JPanel test = new JPanel(); 
                test.setSize(1000, 1000);
                test.setBackground(Color.red);
                swingNode.setContent(test);

            }
        });
    }
```

DroneScreenView, this class just loads the FXML file

```
public class DroneScreenView {

    public DroneScreenView() {
    }

    public void show(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        stage.setTitle("PiStorm - DroneViewScreen");
        stage.setScene(new Scene( FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("droneScreen.fxml"))));
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

The FXML file, droneScreen.fxml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
  <?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
  <?import javafx.embed.swing.*?>
  <?import java.lang.*?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

  <Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="1080.0" minWidth="1920.0" prefHeight="1080.0" prefWidth="1920.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="computer.view.DroneScreenController">
     <children>
        <SwingNode fx:id="cameraNode" layoutX="245.0" layoutY="252.0" />
        <Circle fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="225.0" layoutY="100.0" radius="100.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <ImageView fitHeight="1169.0" fitWidth="1920.0" layoutX="-6.0" layoutY="-8.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
           <image>
              <Image url="@Border%201920x1080.png" />
           </image>
        </ImageView>
     </children>
  </Pane>
```

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] that shows the same issue? It's impossible to tell if things that are obviously omitted (e.g. where do you initialize `cameraNode`?) are errors or are just omitted from the example code.

Comment: I already removed as much as I could. cameraNode isn't initialized anywhere. I thought I didn't have to because it's declared in the FXMl file. Initializing it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: It is the lack of completeness, not the lack of minimality, that is the problem. OK, I see now how `cameraNode` is initialized. Is `LoginView` `DroneScreenView`? And is the FXML file you showed `logInScreen.fxml`, or a different FXML?

Comment: Yes, LoginView is DroneScreenView. I copied the wrong one but it's the same.

Comment: The code just looks confusing. The `show()` method of `DroneScreenView` loads the FXML file, which creates an instance of `DroneScreenController`, which creates another instance of `DroneScreenView`. It's not really clear how you have structured this (it looks very circular). Where do you call each of the `show()` methods? Again, can you make the example into a [MCVE] (emphasis on **complete**)?